# How do I download the .deb file from software center?

Tags: software-center, skype, deb

I have an ASUS k52f and the web cam is mounted upside down. So I have to do a workaround for the web cam to show a proper image.

But the problem is, this workaround only works with Skype 2.x versions. And Skype recently updated to 4.x versions. In the Ubuntu repositories i.e. the software center, they still have the 2.x version.

How do I get the .deb file from the software center so that I could save it and use it in case Ubuntu updates its repositories?

Comment: Can you please specify which Skype version do you want?

Comment: When I open ubuntu software center, this is the version that I downloaded and used 2.2.0.35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Skype 2 is what your after, then you can downloaded it [Here](http://www.wuala.com/TaxiDriver/Linux-Distributionen/skype-debian_2.0.0.72-1_i386.deb/).  And it installs the same way as below.  To download Skype 2.2.0.35 32bit or 64bit [Click here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_import/maya/import/base/skype).

To install Skype 4.x, download it [Here](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/).  Choose 32bit or 64bit depending on your platform.  One downloaded,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the download folder, probably ***Downloads***, and run the command below.

For 32bit

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_i386.deb
```

For 64bit

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_amd64.deb
```

Another way to install . GDebi.  To install it press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal.  When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Or click below

[image]

Once you have installed GDebi, use the File Browser to find the package you wish to install, and double click on it.

Comment: Why the down-vote? :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the link for the download, that version also works well with LD_PRELOAD, but do you have 2.2.0.35. That is the latest version that works with LD_PRELOAD. 4.x does not work with LD_PRELOAD. In the ubuntu repo, they have the 2.2.0.35. If there is anyway i could download that, it would be awesome.

Comment: @VarunSchweinsteigerVenkatesh  I added the download link for 2.2.0.35 in my answer.  See the second line of my answer.  If you feel that this answers your question, you may mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

http://pkgs.org/download/skype

From there, you can download **any version** available until today.
This site is confusing so, don't mess up.

> Select your Linux distro / Skype version
>
> Select 32bit or 64bit
>
> Click "**Select Mirror**"
>
> Then download **Binary Package !**

Skype may require, additional depency files, which you can download from http://pkgs.org

**It's highly recommended to use the latest version**

Good Luck!

Comment: Well,that is exactly what I was looking for. I know it is recommended to use the latest package,but skype 4.x doesnot support LD_PRELOAD which i require since, my webcam is mounted upside down.

Comment: .and,could you please explain what do you mean by **Skype may require, additional depency files** .

Comment: Some programs are not stand alone .deb files. They need other *.deb files to be installed before installing the main program. They are called dependencies (like skype-bin I think ) without those deb files, the main program refuses to be installed. It doesn't matter if you have already installed Skype. There is a web cam virtualizer for Linux, which may help you to fix the issue with Skype 4. Visit : http://www.ws4gl.org/